# How get kubernetes pod metrics periodically and append them to file

Tags: linux, kubernetes, cron, metrics

I am running a load test over a kubernetes pod and i want to sample every 5 minutes the CPU and memory usage of it.
I was currently manually using the linux `top` command over the kubernetes pod.

Is there any way given a `kubernetes pod` to fetch the CPU/Memory usage every X minutes and append it to a file ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this one-liner:

```bash
while [ true ]; do echo $(date) $(date +%s) $(kubectl top -n your-namespace pod $(kubectl get pods -n your-namespace -l your-label-name=your-label-value -o jsonpath='{..metadata.name}') | tail -n 1) | tee -a /path/to/save/your/logs.txt; done
```

Add `sleep 300` to sample it every 5 minutes instead of continuously.

It will find a pod in namespace `your-namespace` with label `your-label-name` that has value `your-label-value`, take its name, and will take only the last one such pod, if you have multiple pods with the same label (that's what `| tail -n 1` for). This way you won't have to determine the name of a pod manually. Then it'll print something like this:

```
Sun, Mar 12, 2023 4:59:05 PM 1678640345 your-pod-name-5c64678fc6-rsldm 47m 657Mi
```

Where `1678640345` is Unix milliseconds timestamp written by `$(date +%s)`. The output will be printed in console (stdout) and mirrored in `/path/to/save/your/logs.txt` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the [metrics server](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server) and then write a small bash script that in a loop that calls some combo of `kubectl top pods --all-namespaces` and outputs to a file. Another option if you want something with some more meat is to run Prometheus and/or [kube-state-metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics) and set it up to scrape metrics from all pods in the system.

Comment: I was looking for some simple `bash` loop that calls `top` every once in a while.